# Sunburst Data Visualization - additional ring

Tags: javascript, data-visualization, infovis, sunburst-diagram, thejit

I found this nice framework for data visualization purposes:
http://thejit.org/static/v20/Jit/Examples/Sunburst/example2.html

For my project I need 4 rings. So I tried to figure out how to add two rings to the template JS, which you can find here: 
http://thejit.org/static/v20/Jit/Examples/Sunburst/example2.js

It is basically a cascaded structure, but simply adding a level doesn't work out.

Does anyone have a clue on how I could add two levels?

In case you have another framework which works a like or similar, I would appreciate your feedback.

Cheers, D

Answer (score 0):

I am wondering the same, will try this at home, but

https://github.com/philogb/jit/blob/master/Source/Options/Options.Node.js

changing dim from 3 to 5 might do it ( assuming the center circle is 1 dim ).

Answer (score 0):

I'm a big fan of the Protovis library, and it easily supports N-level sunbursts: http://mbostock.github.com/protovis/ex/sunburst.html

d3 is another library by the same developer, and it supports sunbursts as well: http://mbostock.github.com/d3/ex/sunburst.html

Answer (score 0):

All I needed to modify was the data: I added some new children to the `children` array of a leaf node and it automatically created a third ring.

The one caveat was that the `id` has to be unique, or only the first instance will be displayed. This may be why your experiments weren't working. It will just skip duplicates without a warning.

See http://philogb.github.io/jit/static/v20/Docs/files/Loader/Loader-js.html for the basic requirements for the JSON format that should be used.